# Editing Content in Drupal

Tags: drupal, content-management-system, drupal-modules

I have an instance of Drupal (Version 9) installed on my local machine.
I want to add users to "Groups" such as "Department X", "Department Y" etc.

This is what I am trying to achieve:

**Department X**

- userA (role - editor)
- userB (role - editor)

**Department Y**

- userC (role - editor)
- userD (role - editor)

I want users within the same department to be able to edit each other's content. For example: "userA" & "userB" can edit each other's content but **not** the content authored by "userC" or "userD".

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

STEP 1: You have to aggregate the roles departmentX and departmentY.

STEP 2: Add the specific role to the user.

STEP 3: Finally you can edit all permission.

*The users should be like this:*

```
Department X

 - userA (role - [editor, departmentX]) 
 - userB (role - [editor, departmentX])

Department Y

 - userC (role - [editor, departmentY]) 
 - userD (role - [editor, departmentY])
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a "Group" module that answers my question.
https://www.drupal.org/project/group